# C - filling struct after initialization - compilation error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, c99

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind the following compilation error (using gcc).

```
0. struct mystruct {
1.     int x;
2.     int y;
3. };
4. 
5. int foo() {
6.     struct mystruct m = {1};    // compiles successfully
7.     m = {2,3};                  // compilation error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
8.     return m.x + m.y;
9. }
```

However, if I cast the value explicitly in line 7, the code compiles:

```
5. int foo() {
6.     struct mystruct m = {1};    // compiles successfully
7.     m = (struct mystruct){2,3}; // compiles successfully
8.     return m.x + m.y;
9. }
```

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this error.
Line 6 compiles successfully without raising an error - the compiler figured out automatically the type of `m` without the explicit casting. Why doesn't it do the same in line 7?

Thanks

Comment: Addressing why it is necessary: How should the compiler know the type of `{ 2, 3 }` outside of an initialization? Could be for example `char [2]` as well as `struct { int a, b; }` etc.

Comment: It could be done the same way like line 6 - using the type of `m`.

Comment: That would be inconsistent with the entire rest of the language. C has no type inference and every expression has a type. `{ 2, 3 }` cannot be an expression as it has no type. The rules, which is allowed where would be horribly complicated, and would make the language less powerful. For example, you can do `void *bar = &(struct mystruct){ 2, 3 };` etc with compound literals.

Comment: I agree that auto-completing the "most-fitting" compound literal, in case the programmer did not write it explicitly, would require complicated rules. Though, this is done in higher languages.

Comment: One design goal of C is to keep the language minimal and simple, many other languages have different design goals. So maybe the answer is just "it's like that to keep the grammar simple".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the symbol `=` is used for both assignment and initialization. The former expects an expression on the right-hand side, which a brace-enclosed initializer list is not.

In your second example, you're not dealing with a cast, but a compound literal, a C99 addition. Semantically, it is equivalent to

```
struct mystruct tmp = {2,3}; // initialization
m = tmp; // assignment
```

Answer (score 4):

The reasoning is that the C90 syntax allows a compound *initializer* only.

In other words, the braced thing on the right hand side of the `=` is an initializer expression, it's *not* a literal of the `struct` type.

C99 adds [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) which make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your line 7 (first chunk) is invalid syntax in C99. An assignment needs an expression on its right, and `{2,3}` is *not* a valid expression.

Your line 6 (first chunk) is an initialization in definition.